# Передача указателей через параметры шаблона

Tags: c++, указатели, шаблоны-с++

Как правильно передавать указатели через параметры шаблона? Пытаюсь так, но получаю ошибки:

```
template<int*>
void f() {}

template<void*>
void f() {}

int main() {
    constexpr int x = 42;
    const int* const x_ptr = &x;
    f<x_ptr>();
}
```

Comment: передаете в шаблонную функцию переменную, нужно тип

Comment: @dreamIIx не только типы можно передавать

Answer (score 1):

Ну во-первых, адрес *локальной* переменной никогда не будет константным выражением, т.е. ни о какой передаче его через параметры шаблона не может быть и речи.

Во-вторых, не ясно как вы собрались передавать указатель на `const int *` туда, где ожидается указатель `int *` или `void *`. В языке С++ таких преобразований неявно выполнено быть не может - это прямое нарушение константной корректности.

В-третьих, чтобы `x_ptr` можно было использовать в качестве аргумента шаблона, он должен быть `constexpr`. Вы, наверное, даже пытались сделать его `constexpr`, но у вас не получилось из-за "во-первых"

```
#include <iostream>

template<int* p> void f() 
{
  std::cout << p << std::endl;
  std::cout << *p << std::endl;
}

int main() 
{
  static int x = 42;
  constexpr int* const x_ptr = &x;
  f<x_ptr>();
}
```

Comment: А что тогда можно передать в эти функции и как?

Comment: @jacob: Парамтеры шаблона должны быть константами времени компиляции - вот что можно туда передавать.

Comment: то есть, например, можно передать просто `nullptr` в `template<void*> f()`?

Comment: @jacob Можно передать адрес переменной `x`, но только если это переменная со статическим хранением.